# tcpdump -z flag problem for run a bash script file

Tags: linux, bash, tcpdump

I have executed the following command to run **tcpdump**:

```bash
# tcpdump -r pcap.pcap -z ./bash.sh -C 1
```

My goal is to run the commands inside the bash.sh file when 1M of the file is read. But this is not happening. The bash.sh file contains a command like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "test" >> /tmp/test.txt
```

The bash.sh file has the executable permission.
I would appreciate it if you could help me with this issue.

Comment: To split your pcap file, use: `tcpdump -nr <(zstdcat myDaily.pcap.zst) -s 0 -w pcapFile- -C 1` ( if your file is conpressed using zstd )

Comment: @JRichardsz No, I didn't

Comment: I think asking the file size and with a cron is the solution